# How to configure ClamAV on Debian 11? (Need sample clamd.conf and correct location)

Tags: debian, configuration, out-of-memory, malware, clamav

Since upgrading from Debian 9 to Debian10/11 Clamscan now runs the system out of memory immediately - instead of previously completing all scans successfully.

But the `/etc/clamav/clamd.conf` file does not exist - nor does any `clamd.conf` file exist on the system.

Where does this file belong? Can we create it ourselves? Where can we get an up to date sample `conf` file?

Answer (score 3):

A sample configuration file is provided as `/usr/share/doc/clamav-daemon/examples/clamd.conf.sample` in the `clamav-daemon` package. If you install that package, you should find a `/etc/clamav/clamd.conf` file too; `dpkg-reconfigure clamav-daemon` will allow you to change its settings.

Note that `clamd.conf` configures the daemon, not `clamscan` itself. If you want to scan using the daemon, you should use `clamdscan` instead.

Current versions of ClamAV [use lots of memory](https://bugs.debian.org/975401), and there doesn’t seem to be any way of reducing the memory requirements.